# WP8 in app purchase in unity

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, unity-game-engine

may be I am asking a basic question, but I am so frustrated. Does anybody recently have implemented in purchase for WP8 in Unity? If yes, then please guide me step by step. I have created IAPs in Dashboard. Please guide me from onward. I have prime31 and WP8Native (Stan's Assets) both plugins. But I don't know what I am missing to implement. As I could not get the actual App ID from new Dashboard.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I am able to manage overall situation. I did everything right, but with wrong App ID. To get proper App Id, launch a less than 1.0.0.0 version for Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 for limited users. You can do this from, App Submission -> Pricing and Availability -> under Distribution and Visibility you can find an option to launch with limited users specified by email addresses.

After launching that you can grab your Actual APP ID in App Management -> App Identity, like,

[image: WP8 Dashboard]